# Uploading a file to GCP using gsutil

Tags: gsutil, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to follow the GCP docs.  I created a bucket called

```
my-awesome-bucketmgtest
```

I am trying to upload a file from MacBook:

```
mark_ginsburg@cloudshell:~$ gsutil cp /tmp/foo.txt gs://my-awesomebucketmgtest
CommandException: No URLs matched: /tmp/foo.txt
mark_ginsburg@cloudshell:~$ gsutil cp file://tmp/foo.txt gs://my-awesome-bucketmgtest
CommandException: No URLs matched: file://tmp/foo.txt
mark_ginsburg@cloudshell:~$ gsutil cp /tmp/foo.txt gs://my-awesome-bucketmgtest
CommandException: No URLs matched: /tmp/foo.txt
mark_ginsburg@cloudshell:~$ gsutil cp tmp/foo.txt gs://my-awesome-bucketmgtest
CommandException: No URLs matched: tmp/foo.txt
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [gsutil docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp), this syntax should work, assuming that /tmp/foo.txt actually exists.

```
gsutil cp /tmp/foo.txt gs://my-awesome-bucketmgtest
```

If you get that error message again, try running `ls /tmp/foo.txt` and see what you get.

EDIT: I just realized that you were trying to run this command in your cloudshell, instead of on your local machine. I recommend that you download the GCloud SDK to your local machine and push it UP...it's just simpler. Alternately, you CAN run it from the destination to pull it up from your laptop, but you need a dedicated IP address for your laptop.

Comment: That command works if /tmp/foo.txt is in the /tmp directory of my Google Cloud Shell.    However I was actually wondering about uploading a file called /tmp/foo.txt that is on my MacBook.  How do I upload that to my bucket?

Comment: @MarkGinsburg gsutil works for uploading from your local machine, too. Just run the command in your local terminal. (You'll need to download the GCloud SDK to do this, obviously.) Literally the first line in the description starts with "The gsutil cp command allows you to copy data between your local file system and the cloud,...." - I'll edit my answer to include the link to the docs. --EDIT oh wait, I already did include the link to the docs, ha! Long day.

Comment: Thanks!  I got the GCloud SDK on the local MacBook and all is well.